# How to change location of SQL Server 2012 database which is already configured with a merge replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have SQL Server 2012 configured with merge replication. currently the location of the replication database and the .mdf and .ldf files reside in `C:\` drive.

The `C:\` drive is now full due to that fact that these files reach over 80GB. Therefore, I want to relocate the files to another drive where I have more space with out affecting the replication and the data.

How do I do this safely?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584938/move-sql-server-2008-database-files-to-a-new-folder-location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh Boy! [System Databases on C Drive are recipe for disaster](http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/system-databases-on-c-drive/) !

[Change the default database location](http://thomaslarock.com/2015/02/changing-default-database-file-locations-in-sql-server/) away from C:\ drive.

You can do it using `ALTER DATABASE .. MODIFY FILE`

1. Change the db file location

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE db_name
   MODIFY FILE (NAME = logical_data_file, 
        FILENAME = 'D:\data\physical_file.mdf');

   ALTER DATABASE db_name
   MODIFY FILE (NAME = logical_file, 
        FILENAME = 'L:\log\physical_file_log.ldf');
   ```
2. **Stop log reader agent, distribution and merge agent (if they are running).**
3. Offline the database using `alter database db_name set offline`
4. Once offline, you have to PHYSICALLY move the data and log files to the new location that you put in in step 1.
5. Bring the database ONLINE `alter database db_name set ONLINE`
6. Start the jobs that were disabled in step 2.